# Retrieving data in HTML from a database using Java (no javascript, no java servlet or any other language)

Tags: java, html, mysql, database, multithreading

How to create a multi-threaded web server in java which is capable of retrieving all the data of students from a database table and display them on a webpage in a table format when the request is passed from a local web browser client.

Can I get method for displaying data in html?

Comment: Well, do something with a ServerSocket, a Thread, a JDBC connection, and something to print the result. I cannot image you expect StackOverflow to solve your homework, right?

Comment: @apomene - I have written the code to retrieve the database in the java console but I don't know how to pass on data to html file.

Comment: @java_fearer You don't have any web experience, do you? Okay, don't care about those for a moment (you need to send the HTML output via HTTP though). If you study those things I've mentioned in my answer, the servlet container and the template engine will take care of those things for ya. BTW do not be suprised if users thumb your question down or even flag it. It pretty much feels like trying to have the community solve your homework - what would you learn from that? (I see you got your first thumb-down meanwhile ;))

Comment: @Powerslave- people might be thinking that its a homework, though its not. I need to learn how to do it.

Comment: @java_fearer If that's your ambition, I have to say it's nice. The shortest answer I can give you is 4 characters: J2EE. Of course, this depends on what you are going for - the industry standard of developing Java-based web apps or misc topics like threading, using JDBC and Sockets, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, creating a mockup web server does not make sense.

If the goal of your task is to provide a web application with the required functionality, then install a [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/), and use [Spring MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) in conjunction with [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) and [JSP](http://www.jsptut.com/) to build the website.

Using [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) with a [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) plugin greatly simplifies your work.

If that does not fit, do the same, but first implement your own [Servlet Container](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/05/14/java_webserver.html) in substitution of *Tomcat*.